# How do I resolve Internet Explorer setTimeout Issues?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have been working with setTimeout on some coding for a few days and it worked on my main testing browser, Chrome. Once I checked the feature on different browsers, Internet Explorer gave me an issue and did not work at all. The other browsers also worked.

```
$(childWindow).load(function()
{
    var dateObject = new Date();
    var startTime = Date.now() + (dateObject.getTimezoneOffset() - 300) * 60000; // GMT -5
    var currentTime = startTime();
    var counter = 0;
    var runningFunction = function()
    {
        var remainingTime = Math.round((startTime + 10 * 1000 - (Date.now() + (dateObject.getTimezoneOffset() - 300) * 60000)) / 1000);

        if (remainingTime > 0)
        {
            // update timer in HTML which is not shown

            currentTime = Date.now() + (dateObject.getTimezoneOffset() - 300) * 60000;

            var nextCounter = 100 - (currentTime - (startTime + (counter * 100))); // compensate for browser drifting

            counter++;

            childWindow.setTimeout(runningFunction, nextCounter); // try to update nearly at 100 milliseconds every 100 milliseconds
        }
    };

    childWindow.setTimeout(runningFunction, 100); // initially update at 100 milliseconds

    // other jQuery coding used
});
```

This is only a portion of the code but where I believe the problem lies. Some logic or syntax may be incorrect but that is not the problem I have. After 10 seconds, there should not be a setTimeout call since remainingTime would be negative so there really is no "infinite loop". With this (partial) code, it works flawlessly in Chrome and executes every 100 milliseconds. In Internet Explorer, nothing happens at all. I read on other Stack Overflow posts and other external resources that the syntax should be `setTimeout(function() { calleeFunction(); }, time);`

I tried changing `var runningFunction = function()` to `function runningFunction()` and the `setTimeout` function portion to `function() { runningFunction(); }` which does work but completely hangs in Chrome and Internet Explorer eventually leading to some stack error (I think it was Script 28 in IE) during the 10 seconds "infinite" `setTimeout` call loop.

Another solution I tried was `var runningFunction = (function() { ... }());` but then this line is executed before the `childWindow.setTimeout(runningFunction, 100);` line. I want the variable to be just declared but not executed until the `childWindow.setTimeout` line is called. I wouldn't mind putting the anonymous function inside the `setTimeout` function but I am actually using this exact line in other parts of the program to act as restarting the timer and the function itself is over 200 lines long so I wouldn't want to copy the same 200 lines in multiple parts of the program.

**Code Based on Oriol's Response / Update**

```
$(childWindow).load(function()
{
    $.post("x.php", { a: "", b: "", c: "" }, function(data)
    {
        if (data !== "")
            $("div:first", childWindow.document).html(data);
        else
        {
            var dateObject = new Date(),
            startTime = aux(),
            currentTime,
            counter = 0;

            function aux() {
                return +new Date() + (dateObject.getTimezoneOffset() - 300) * 6e4;
            }

            function runningFunction()
            {
                console.log('runningFunction');

                var currentAux = aux(),
                remainingTime = Math.round(  10 + (startTime - currentAux) / 1e3  );

                if (remainingTime > 0)
                {
                    $("div:first", childWindow.document).html("<div>" + remainingTime + "</div>");

                    currentTime = currentAux;

                    var nextCounter = Math.max(0, 100 - currentTime + startTime + counter * 100); 
                    // compensate for browser drifting

                    counter++;

                    childWindow.setTimeout(runningFunction, nextCounter); 
                    // try to update nearly at 100 milliseconds every 100 milliseconds
                }
            }

            $("div:first", childWindow.document).html("<div>Random message.</div>");

            if (childWindow.document.hasFocus() && childWindow.outerWidth >= 0.90 * screen.availWidth && childWindow.outerHeight >= 0.90 * screen.availHeight)
            {
                var pauseTime = "";
                var running = true;

                childWindow.setTimeout(runningFunction, 100);
            }
            else
            {
                var pauseTime = startTime;
                var running = false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The fiddle provided does work but it does not work on the website. Based on this coding, the only way `setTimeout` wouldn't get executed is if the last if statement block is false. I have put a console.log message inside the true statement and it did return that message so I know IE is executing that block therefore it has to get to `setTimeout` line. Again, with this coding, the same situation occurs as it was initially posted, Chrome displays the console.log message in the function every ~100 milliseconds and IE doesn't even consider the function at all. I am really running at a dead end with this.

Comment: There appears to be an unbalanced `)` in this line: `var startTime = Date.now() + (dateObject.getTimezoneOffset() - 300) * 60000);` Syntax like this can cause unexpected results. If this is not your actual code, you might want to edit your question and update it with your actual (correct) code.

Comment: I mentioned that some syntax in the code were not correct as this is a partial code. The functionality inside the function works, just not the setTimeout portion in IE.

Comment: `This is only a portion of the code but where I believe the problem lies` - so does this exact code cause the problem in your IE?  If not, please provide a sample that does.

Comment: Which IE? Until IE9 there is no [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) support. You can use `+new Date()`

Comment: Have you tried looking at the console to check for error messages? You should create a simple fiddle that demonstrates what works in Chrome and does not work in IE.

Comment: Oriol: The IE version I'm using is IE 11. I'll change Date.now() for older IE versions using your suggestion. Thank you.

jahroy: No errors are shown in the console log. I can't use a fiddle since I have $.post requests to my server. I have inserted test console log messages and all of them appear outside the function variable. Any console log test messages I put inside the function variables does not show in the console log in IE (does show in other browsers) therefore IE is not picking up the function from the setTimeout call at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems:

- Syntax errors
- Until IE9 there is no `Date.now()` support. You can use `+new Date()`
- Most times `nextCounter` is negative, so the delayed function doesn't run on IE. You can use `Math.max(0, nextCounter)`.

This works:

```
var dateObject = new Date(),
    startTime = aux(),
    currentTime,
    counter = 0;
function aux() {
    return +new Date() + (dateObject.getTimezoneOffset() - 300) * 6e4;
}
function runningFunction()
{
    console.log('runningFunction');

    var currentAux = aux(),
        remainingTime = Math.round(  10 + (startTime - currentAux) / 1e3  );

    if (remainingTime > 0)
    {
        // update timer in HTML which is not shown

        currentTime = currentAux;

        var nextCounter = Math.max(0, 100 - currentTime + startTime + counter * 100); 
        // compensate for browser drifting

        counter++;

        childWindow.setTimeout(runningFunction, nextCounter); 
        // try to update nearly at 100 milliseconds every 100 milliseconds
    }
};

childWindow.setTimeout(runningFunction, 100); 
// initially update at 100 milliseconds
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hT3w9/5/)

Comment: Still the same situation. I receive the console log message in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @secretply Did you try the demo? It works on IE8 for me.

Comment: The demo works but not on the website. I hope it has nothing to do that I'm on localhost and not on a live website, which I don't see how it could be. I edited the original post with addition of your code and the code that is being used.

Comment: @secretply [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hT3w9/8/). You can't use function declarations inside conditionals.